# Как перенести в массив файл .txt в Си?

Tags: c, файлы

Есть файл .txt со словами, цифрами -- набор символов, грубо говоря. Нужно всё содержимое файла (файл может быть любого размера с любым количеством символов) перенести в один большой массив, чтобы работать над его содержимым. Как это сделать?

Спасибо за ответы!

Comment: fopen, fseek, ftell, fseek, malloc. fread. fclose. как-то так, например

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой способ
1.Узнаем размер файла
2.Аллоцируем память размером с файл
3.Читаем из файла в память
4.Что-то делаем

Answer (score 1):

В зависимости от операционной системы используйте либо mmap() (unix), либо CreateFileMapping() + MapViewOfFile() (windows) - получите сразу файл в виде большого массива :-).